# Url with umlaut (non ascii), dashes and brackets is not parseable by requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, unicode, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to get the HTML content of a page with requests, but it results in `UnicodeDecodeError`. The reproducible code:

```py
import requests
import urllib

url = "https://www.unique.nl/vacature/coördinator-facilitair-(v2037635)"
```

Attempt 1:

```py
requests.get(url)
```

Attempt 2:

```py
requests.get(requests.utils.requote_uri(url))
```

Both result in `UnicodeDecodeError`

Attempt 3:

```py
requests.get(urllib.parse.quote(url))
```

Attempt 4:

```py
requests.get(urllib.parse.quote(url.encode("Latin-1"), ":/"))
```

What am I missing here. Also encoding it to `utf-8`, `latin1` or `unicode_escape`, does not work.

Full error message:

```
File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py:75, in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     64 def get(url, params=None, **kwargs):
     65     r"""Sends a GET request.
     66
     67     :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
   (...)
     72     :rtype: requests.Response
     73     """
---> 75     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py:61, in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     57 # By using the 'with' statement we are sure the session is closed, thus we
     58 # avoid leaving sockets open which can trigger a ResourceWarning in some
     59 # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     60 with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 61     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:542, in Session.request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    537 send_kwargs = {
    538     'timeout': timeout,
    539     'allow_redirects': allow_redirects,
    540 }
    541 send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 542 resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    544 return resp

File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:677, in Session.send(self, request, **kwargs)
    674 if allow_redirects:
    675     # Redirect resolving generator.
    676     gen = self.resolve_redirects(r, request, **kwargs)
--> 677     history = [resp for resp in gen]
    678 else:
    679     history = []

File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:677, in <listcomp>(.0)
    674 if allow_redirects:
    675     # Redirect resolving generator.
    676     gen = self.resolve_redirects(r, request, **kwargs)
--> 677     history = [resp for resp in gen]
    678 else:
    679     history = []

File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:150, in SessionRedirectMixin.resolve_redirects(self, resp, req, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies, yield_requests, **adapter_kwargs)
    146 """Receives a Response. Returns a generator of Responses or Requests."""
    148 hist = []  # keep track of history
--> 150 url = self.get_redirect_target(resp)
    151 previous_fragment = urlparse(req.url).fragment
    152 while url:

File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:116, in SessionRedirectMixin.get_redirect_target(self, resp)
    114     if is_py3:
    115         location = location.encode('latin1')
--> 116     return to_native_string(location, 'utf8')
    117 return None

File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/_internal_utils.py:25, in to_native_string(string, encoding)
     23         out = string.encode(encoding)
     24     else:
---> 25         out = string.decode(encoding)
     27 return out

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 29: invalid start byte
```

Comment: URLs cannot contain non-ASCII characters. Any non-ASCII character needs to be URL-encoded.

Comment: Please [edit] to reveal the full traceback in each case.

Comment: @deceze see attempt 2. It is percent encoded to non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Added error message below and also 4th attempt trying to URL encode. @tripleee

Comment: At the peril of repeating myself, please [edit] to reveal the full traceback in each case.

Comment: Made an edit and also it is not clear from the duplicate link how it can help this question (see my comment above). Can you consider re-opening? @deceze

Comment: Came here for help. My question get's closed in 2 min, with a link which is not helping and the method I tried to apply (partly?) covers the duplicate link. Always a great experience posting questions on SO. Since some "experts" forgot that at one point they had to learn as well. Thanks! If you ever need help with SQL, data analytics or statistics, feel free to contact me. I won't close your question in 2 mins ;) @deceze

Comment: The point is that the URL should not contain an umlaut to begin with. It should be some `%..` sequence. You shouldn’t do this after the fact, you should write the URL canonically with percent encoding from the beginning. Is that not a possibility for you somehow?

Comment: It is part of our webscraper and it is a redirect link from the page before which we retrieve automatically.

Comment: Can you detail how you got the link? Because if you present it as source code literal, there’s the additional complication of how your source code file is encoded exactly.

Comment: Interesting, attempt 4 works by just using vanilla python, eg: `urllib.request.urlopen`. Might this be a `requests` bug?

Comment: `"https://www.unique.nl/vacature/co%C3%B6rdinator-facilitair-(v2037635)"` works with `urllib.request.urlopen`, but not with `requests.get` and results in the same error the OP received.  Somewhere `requests.get` is converting the string to latin1.

Comment: If `requests` can't parse the data it gets back from the web site, the web site is misconfigured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the *request URL* that's the problem, it's the *response* that `requests` can't parse. Here are the response headers of that URL:

```
HTTP/2 301 
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Tue, 27 Dec 2022 07:37:34 GMT
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
location: https://unique.nl/vacature/co?rdinator-facilitair-(v2037635)
content-length: 184
arr-disable-session-affinity: true
```

The `location` header contains a URL with unencoded non-ASCII characters. **That is the problem.** URLs by specification may not contain non-ASCII characters. Standards conforming HTTP clients are within their right to crash on this malformed response. The URL *must* be percent-encoded.

Other clients *may not* crash because they treat the response in some other way that doesn't happen to cause a problem, but it's still the response that's deviating from the standard.

Comment: This clears it up, thanks. Still interesting that `urllib` parses it correctly, while `requests` does not. Especially since requests uses urllib under the hood. Will open a ticket on GH to see what other (devs) think of this case.